# Changing background color in one field when compared to another field using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am creating a meal plan for a homework assignment in my JavaScript class and I have everything working except for this one part. Both of the input fields are numbers not text.

> If the sum of the calories from the selected meals is greater than their targeted intake, the calories count box will display the calories sum in a red background with bold white letters, otherwise, a green background with black letter

```
function changeCount() {
  var target = parseFloat( document.getElementById("target") ).value;
  var count = parseFloat( document.getElementById("count") ).value;
  if ( count.value < target.value ) {
    count.classList.add("good");
  } else {
    count.classList.add("over");
  }
}
```

Comment: 1. remove `parseFloat` and `.value` from the first two declarations. 2.`if (parseFloat(count.value) < parseFloat(target.value))` (also note that it's WAY too early for you to be posting here, and your actual question has nothing to with changing a background color)

Comment: You are invoking parse on elements.

Answer (score 0):

You just needed to remove `parseFloat` and .`value` from the declaration and use it when comparing

```js
function changeCount(){
  var target = document.getElementById("target"),
    count = document.getElementById("count");
  
  if (count.value < target.value){
    count.classList.add("good");      
    count.classList.remove("over");
  } else {
    count.classList.add("over");
    count.classList.remove("good");
  }
}
```

```css
.good{
  background-color: green;
  color:white;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.over{
  background-color: red;
  color:white;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="target" placeholder="target" />
<input type="text" id="count" placeholder="count" />
<input type="button" value="calculate" onclick="changeCount()" />
```

Comment: Alright thank I got it working, but is there a way for that to loop when count field is changed? Because I have checkboxes that increase the count total every time one is clicked.

Comment: Sure. Just call the same function in the checkboxs' `onchange` attribute